# import csv file to mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to import a csv to a MySQL database using the following PHP code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(1);

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbase1;host=localhost;charset=utf8', 'admin', 'admin');
$pdo->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try{

$query = $pdo->prepare("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/feed.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE `tablename`

fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '\"'
lines terminated by '\n'

(field1, field2, field3)");

$query->execute();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

When I run this, I see no errors, and the data has not been imported to the table.

If I try running the same code within phpmyadmin, the data is successfully imported.

Comment: Did you try to set  `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE` when constructing the PDO object?

Comment: Like so: `$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbase1;host=localhost;charset=utf8', 'admin', 'admin', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true));`

Comment: Just tried same error

Comment: PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY fixed the error

Comment: but the data is not being imported?

Comment: try adding your code into a `try` `catch` block so that you can see if it is throwing any exceptions

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: just tried and updated question - no messages are shown